# Game Maker - Not all objects work

Tags: game-maker

This is my code (Placed in a step event)

```
if (place_meeting(x,y,Obj_Player))
{
    time = 50
}
if (time > 0)
{
    Obj_Player.jsp = 17;
}
else
{
    Obj_Player.jsp = 12;
}
if (time > 0) time -= 1;
```

Placed in a create event:

```
image_speed = 0.4;
time = 0;
new = 17
```

For some reason, one object with this code will work, but the rest will not.  I've no idea why and I need multiple items in the room.

Also, the items in the create event, I would like to move into the creation code of each individual item.  I only want to edit `new` so will I have to move all the code or just `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Obj_Player.blablabla`, GMS will get first created instance of the object. You need use function which will return `id` of instance. For example, `instance_place()`. I'm not sure what exactly you doing, so code can be unusable:

Example with one global timer for all instances:

```
var obj = instance_place(x, y, Obj_Player);
if obj != noone
{
    with Obj_Player
    {
        time = 50;
    }
}

with Obj_Player
{
    if (time > 0) time--;
}
```

Next is `Obj_Player`:

```
// Create
time = 0;

// Step
if time > 0
    jsp = 17;
else
    jsp = 12;
```

Example with an independent local timer for each instance:

```
var obj = instance_place(x, y, Obj_Player);
if obj != noone
    obj.time = 50;
```

Next is `Obj_Player`:

```
// Create
time = 0;

// Step
if time > 0
    jsp = 17;
else
    jsp = 12;

if (time > 0) time--;
```

**upd:**

> Just to clarify, I have one Obj_Player and multiple items which contain the code.

I think I understand what you trying to do

Obj_Player, Create:

```
time = 0;
```

Obj_Player, Collision event (with your object):

```
time = 50;
```

Obj_Player, Step event:

```
time--;
if time > 0
    jsp = 17;
else
    jsp = 12;
```

That's all.

As you can see, all code placed at `Obj_Player`. Because when you do

```
if time > 0
    Obj_Player.jsp = 17;
else
    Obj_Player.jsp = 12;
```

and you have multiple instances with this code, `jsp` will be `17` only when *all* instances will has `time > 0`. Actually, `jsp` will contain result of check of the last instance (as the last check anyway will replace any previous results).

---

> Also, the items in the create event, I would like to move into the creation code of each individual item. I only want to edit `new` so will I have to move all the code or just `new`?

Only `new`. Firstly will be called `Create` event (if we're talking about GMS, not about GM8) and then `Creation code`, so using `Creation code` you can just modify all, what was in `Create` event.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but now none of the items work.  Just to clarify, I have one Obj_Player and multiple items which contain the code.

Comment: I updated answer. BTW, if `new` variable has realtion to magic numbers in `jsp` variable, then you can receive this value in `Collision` event, using something like `new_value = other.new;` and `if time > 0 jsp = new_value; else ...`